# string function: insert - self implemented via a copy function

Tags: c, string, insert

i got a new task from my teach to implement some basic string operations like append, remove, substr and insert.

while i was thinking at how should i approach this problem i thought i could just write a function which does the copying and ...

```
int copy(char* buffer,char * string,int begin,int end)
{
    if(end == 0)
        end = length(string);

    //Copy from begin to end and save result into buffer
    for(int i = 0; i < end;i++)
        buffer[i] = *(string+begin+i);

    return end;
}
```

with that implementation, so my idea i could just implement all the other functions asked by my teacher like this :

```
void insert(char* buffer,char * string, char * toInsert, int begin,int end)
{
    //Copy till the position of the original string
     begin = copy(buffer,
                  string,0,begin);

    //Insert
    //copy from the last change of the original string
     begin = copy(buffer+begin,
                  toInsert,0,end);

    //Copy whats left
    copy(buffer+begin,
         string);
```

}

So if i now try to insert something with this function i get some weird output:

```
int main() {

char * Hallo       = "Hello World how are things?";
char * appendix    = "Halt die schnauze!";

char buffer[128];
for (int i = 0; i < 128;i++)
    buffer[i] = -0;



insert(buffer,Hallo,appendix,5,0);
printf("%s\n",buffer);

return 0;
}
```

output: ***HelloHalt die schnHello World how are things?***

I simply cannot get my head around why the output does look like this. Do i have a logical mistake there?

Comment: For your `length` and `copy` and `append` and `substr` functions, I suggest you have a look at the perhaps similar standard library functions `strlen` and `strcpy` and `strcat` and `strstr` *and their variants* to see how those functions are declared. Perhaps you can find some open source implementations, to see how others do it.

Comment: What's the expected behavior of `insert` and what's the expected output given your current input?

Comment: the expected output would be: " HelloHalt die schnauze!how are things?"

insert should insert any string into another one and save result in buffer.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for the suggestion,

Comment: `" HelloHalt die schnauze!how are things?"` : Why removed ` World ` ?

Comment: yeah... a big fat typo from my side XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t length(const char *s){
    size_t len = 0;
    while(*s++){
        ++len;
    }
    return len;
}

int copy(char *buffer, const char *string, int begin, int end){
    int len = 0;//copy length

    if(end == 0)
        end = length(string);

    for(int i = begin; i < end; i++)//End position is not included
        buffer[len++] = string[i];

    return len;
}

void insert(char *buffer, const char *string, const char *toInsert, int begin, int end){
    int len;
    len  = copy(buffer, string, 0, begin);
    len += copy(buffer + len, toInsert, 0, end);
    len += copy(buffer + len, string, begin, end);
    buffer[len] = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char * Hallo = "Hello World how are things?";
    char * appendix = "Halt die schnauze!";
    char buffer[128] = {0};

    insert(buffer, Hallo, appendix, 5, 0);
    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    return 0;
}
```